# $compile:html error in loading page

Tags: angularjs

```
Error: [$compile:tplrt] Template for directive 'tdLsoMessages' must have exactly one root element. tpl/lsoMessages.tpl.html
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.29/$compile/tplrt?p0=tdLsoMessages&p1=tpl%2FlsoMessages.tpl.html
    at app.min.js:1
    at app.min.js:1
    at app.min.js:2
    at k (app.min.js:2)
    at k (app.min.js:2)
    at app.min.js:2
    at k.$eval (app.min.js:2)
    at k.$digest (app.min.js:2)
    at k.$apply (app.min.js:2)
    at i (app.min.js:2)
```

Comment: Hardly a well composed question.

Answer (score 0):

It means your directive HTML is not a root of one element.

```
<div>

</div>
<span>

</span>
```

This is not valid because it is 2 separate elements. To solve, simply wrap those in a div.

```
<div>
    <div>

    </div>
    <span>

    </span>
</div>
```

Now it is a singular element, with child elements.